In OpenMPI, is there a way to put jobs on specific cores?
The question pretty much says it all.  This is for benchmarking purposes.  I really do need to target specific cores on specific nodes.  Targeting particular nodes is not enough in and of itself for this project.  I am told that you can do this with a hostfile, but the only documentation I can find on hostfiles discusses only telling OpenMPI how many slots are available on a node, not which specific slot(s) to use.
